# What is the use of Test/Unit folder in module ? What is the purpose?

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, folder

In magento 2, I see in so many modules that there are **Test/Unit** folder available. I know little bit about that it used for unit test purpose.

But, I want to know that :

- What is the purpose of this folder?
- Advantage / Disadvantage
- Actual use

Can any one eloborate in details with example ?

except this links :

- https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-checkout-customization/
- https://inchoo.net/magento-2/unit-testing-magento-2/

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/test/unit/unit_test_execution_cli.html

Comment: Yes bro. I read that. But, I want to know in brief with example. Want to know what's actual purpose of that. How to implement in custom module?

Comment: Yes, we can and we can also check dependency of the class from terminal :) I'll give you example by tonight... I checked this one from Vinai Kopp's blog. Which was amazing

Comment: Please check this tutorial of Max Pronko https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQedsx6gbmI&feature=youtu.be. It will help you.

Comment: okay @Ram. But, if you can eloborate then please put as answer with example.

Comment: Actually @Rohan I don't have much idea about this. I saw this video couple of days ago. It looks great to me so I shared with you.

Comment: @RohanHapani did you got an answer for this with example?

Answer (score 0):

Unit test case are useful for validate a piece of code. where it is returning expected output or not.lets take following example. 
 In megento we have customer login module. today i wrote some test cases and executed. after some days i have changed some functionality related to customer login module. now i need to check all the scenarios. In that case i go and run all the existing scenarios and check all are valid or not. it means we can validate immediately  whatever changed functionality  effecting existing scenarios or not. this it main advantage of test cases. we are maintaining set of records to validate particular module/functionality.

lets take login module, by default we have authenticate($username, $password) in **AccountManagement.php** and test case also available for this authenticate method

Now i added new functionality like login with "username"/"mobile number" or email. instead of only email. now i added test case for newly added functionality. now it is working fine. after that i need to cross verify existing all the scenarios whether is any thing effected of not.

Comment: Can you please give me programmatically that example?